# I want to know,how does 'category' knows which model to access

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

template code-

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'home' %}">All Products</a>
    {% for category in links %}
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{category.get_url}}">{{category}}</a>
    {% endfor %}
```

context_processor.py

```
def menu_links(request):
    links=Category.objects.all()
    return dict(links=links)
```

Category Model-

```
class Category (models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    description=models.TextField(blank=True)
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to='category',blank=True)

    def get_url(self):
        return reverse('products_by_category',args=[self.slug])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Product model-

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    description=models.TextField(blank=True)
    category=models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to='product',blank=True)
    stock=models.IntegerField()
    available=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def get_url(self):
        return reverse('product_detail',args=[self.category.slug,self.slug])

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.name
```

here, as you can see the `def get_url(self)` is in `Category` as well as `Product` model
I just want to know how come category in `{{category.get_url}}` knows to access the method in `Category` and not in `Product` model

Comment: Because it is a `Category` object, that is how object-oriented programming works (in Python).

Answer (score 1):

```py
class Foo:
    def blah():
        return "blah by foo"

class Bar:
    def blah():
        return "blah by bar"

f = Foo()
f.blah()
```

This is analogous to what is happening in your example. No reason (i.e. no way) for `f` to access anything from `Bar` class.

In your example, there are some steps in between, namely, there is a list of objects, and the list is then passed to the template and looped over. But that is not relevant, items inside that list are still of the same type (i.e. each item still is still an instance of `Category`), nothing has changed them to `Product` (which would be very very strange if it did, though technically possible in Python).